# How can I use VBA to enable multiple Excel drop down lists that enter a different value from what the user selects?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, drop-down-menu

This is my first attempt at using VBA. I'm adapting a script offered by Contextures.com that goes with "Excel drop down list automatically changes product name to code" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLJEMnIT0zM). I've successfully created on dropdown that adds the ID that is associated with the parameter type that a user selected (e.g. when the user selects "Chlorophyll" from a dropdown on the data entry Excel worksheet, Excel enters the ID number associated with that parameter name in the same cell, based on a list contained in a table on a second worksheet). However, when I try to add more options, the script stops working. The adapted code adds two ElseIf statements for other column dropdowns.

When the script runs it doesn't report any errors. Also, oddly, it occasionally works on the first go. The code is below.

Many thanks in advance for your assistance.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

If Target.Column = 2 Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo exitHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Worksheets("CHLA Maps").Range("B1") _
        .Offset(Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .Match(Target.Value, Worksheets("CHLA Maps").Range("paramTypeList"), 0), 0)
Exit Sub

ElseIf Target.Column = 3 Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo exitHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Worksheets("CHLA Maps").Range("F1") _
        .Offset(Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .Match(Target.Value, Worksheets("CHLA Maps").Range("labMethodList"), 0), 0)
    Exit Sub    
ElseIf Target.Column = 4 Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo exitHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Worksheets("CHLA Maps").Range("J1") _
        .Offset(Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .Match(Target.Value, Worksheets("CHLA Maps").Range("parameterQCCodeList"), 0), 0)
    Exit Sub
Else
    Exit Sub   
End If
exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the exit subs in the if statements, the logic will drop out anyway.  The current exit subs will not allow the application.enableevents= true to execute and the event processing will stop

I can’t seem to comment, don’t think this is really a full answer for you.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the exit subs, but no change. Definitely works the first time I use one of the dropdowns. Thanks anyway, Art.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the target.column = 2 (select it and press F9), then change a value in column C, you can use the F8 key to step through the logic to see what isn’t doing what you expect. From here the code looks ok

Comment: You also might need to turn events back on, you can use the immediate window (Carl-g) to run the application.enableevets= true

Comment: Adding application.enableevents = true at the end of each expression block worked. Really pleased to get this working, thanks so much for your time, Art.